# Get name of lane in Fastfile

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm setting up a `Fastfile` for `fastlane`, and I'm trying to switch on the lane name that fastlane is beeing run with.

Say I run `fastlane wow`

In this `Fastfile`, I want to get the name of the current lane that `fastlane`was called with, which is `"wow"`:

```
wowness = (lane[:lane-name] == "wow" ? "Much wow" : "Not so wow")
puts wowness

lane :wow do |options|
    puts "print something random"
end
```

As far as I understand the `fastlane` uses Ruby, so maybe this could be the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I think i got it. I made this nifty little lane:

```
lane :get_lane_name do 
    lanename = ""
    ARGV.each do |a|
            lanename = "#{a}"
    end
    lanename
end
```

I use it like this:

```
build_type = (get_lane_name == "beta" ? "Staging" : "Production")
puts build_type
```

Comment: Can just use ```
lane :get_lane_name do 
  ARGV.first
end``` ?

Answer (score 6):

```rb
ENV["FASTLANE_LANE_NAME"] 
# or
lane_context[SharedValues::LANE_NAME]
```

ref: https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/lanes/#lane-properties